# Scenarios under which JVM gets killed?

Tags: java, scala, jvm

I am thinking of all the scenarios where JVM could get killed because of Programming Errors?

SomeOne claimed that `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` will not cause `JVM` to get killed, but when I run my program to assert, this was not found to be true. I tried [this](http://crunchify.com/how-to-generate-out-of-memory-oom-in-java-programatically/) program

Where can I find list of `recoverable` and `un-receoverable` errors?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JVM will stop

- when it crashes due to a bug in the JVM
- when all the non-daemon threads stop running
- when invoking System.exit()

An Exception or an Error being thrown never stops the JVM. What it can do, though, if it's not caught, if to cause the thread from which it's called to terminate its execution. And if it's the last non-daemon thread to run, then the JVM will stop.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("still running...");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000L);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // ignore: I don't want to die
                }
            }
        }
    };

    Thread neverEndingThread = new Thread(r);
    neverEndingThread.start();

    List<byte[]> arrays = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        byte[] hugeArray = new byte[2_000_000_000];
        arrays.add(hugeArray);
    }
    System.out.println(arrays);
}
```

Executing this code will start a new thread, and then will cause an OutOfMemoryError to be thrown from the main thread. Since this error is not caught by the main thread, the main thread stops executing. But the JVM doesn't stop, because the never ending thread continues to run.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to mistake *non-recoverable* as synonymous with a *JVM exit*.

In practice OOME, ThreadDeath and SOE are non-recoverable because they can occur asynchronously at almost any point in the code, including JDK-internal objects and leave them in inconsistent state.

This can lead to all kinds of undefined behavior, *but that does not necessarily mean a JVM exit*. Livelocks, deadlocks or simply incorrect results are also possible.

And then there are external causes for the JVM to be killed. Which, again, has nothing to do with non-recoverable errors.

Answer (score 1):

> I am thinking of all the scenarios where JVM could get killed because of Programming Errors?

It depends on what you mean by "killed".

If you call `System.exit(0);` incorrectly, this will exit the program.

Also if you use Unsafe incorrectly or trigger a signal in native code this will also cause the program to exit.

While an `Error` might be considered unrecoverable, this doesn't stop the process even though this might be desirable.  You can trap this sort of Error and log it before exiting.

```
try {
    many operations

} catch(Error e) {
    // log the error

    // force the program to shutdown
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

Note: if you discard the error the thread will keep running and if one thread dies, it doesn't kill the remaining threads unless they are all daemon threads.

Note also: you can generate an OutOfMemoryError very easily like this

```
try {
   throw new OutOfMemoryError("Just because...");

} catch (Error e) {
   // pretend it didn't happen.
}
// thread continues...
```